# How to subtract n months from a DateTime in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, datetime

I'm new in ruby and date arithmetics seems confusing.

How can I remove *n* months from a `DateTime` without using any other modules?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `DateTime` is a subclass of `Date`, you can use [`<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3C) or [`prev_month`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-prev_month):

```
require 'date'

d = DateTime.now    #=> #<DateTime: 2018-02-20T15:39:44+01:00 ...>
d << 4              #=> #<DateTime: 2017-10-20T15:39:44+01:00 ...>
d.prev_month(4)     #=> #<DateTime: 2017-10-20T15:39:44+01:00 ...>
```

Note that `DateTime` doesn't account for daylight savings time.

Comment: next_month works! Thanks for useful link of documentation

Comment: thank you for not suggesting to use `ActiveSupport::Duration`